# NodeMCU - Access Point mode or Station mode?

Tags: webserver, iot, esp8266, nodemcu, access-point

I'm new to Nodemcu and i need your recommendations.

I'm curently doing an IOT project that can be worked in the large area and I decide to use Nodemcu - ESP8266 to transfer the data. I plan to use 3 Nodemcu to demo. Two of them are used for collecting data from sensors and transfer them to the 3rd Nodemcu. The 3rd Nodemcu will act like a gateway and it will recongnize the data from each node and send it to the Web Server that I myself created. The Web has its own domain and hosting.

With the ideas above, i have some questions:

1. Do i really need the 3rd nodemcu to send data to Web Server? Or i just need to send the data directly from those 2 nodemcu to a Web Server?
2. If it's possible to use the 3rd nodemcu, so it should be worked in station or access point mode?
3. If 3rd nodemcu is not necessary, so how can i extend the working range of the project?

Thanks so much for your helps. I'm really appreciated. Sorry for my bad English too.

Answer (score 0):

NODEMCU can be used to send data to the server directly if it connects with a router via WiFi(Router needs to be internet connected).

1. You don't need the third Nodemcu to transfer data. Both esp8266 is directly connected with a router to send data to the server. MQTT is the best protocol for sending data to the server from Sensor. NodeMCU works as an MQTT client to send data. You need to host MQTT broker on a cloud server. Server store data into the database.
2. If you want to use a third NodeMcu device. NodeMcu can support access point + station parallelly. An access point is used to get data from both devices. ESP8266 station is used to transfer data to the server.
3. All devices need to have into the same WiFi network to transfer data in between. In case of transferring data to the server, One solution is, To use WiFi range extender like Google WiFi.

You can use MQTTfx desktop application to send and receive data from NodeMcu(ESP8266).

MQTT library for ESP8266

https://github.com/Imroy/pubsubclient

Use the Following link to get more familiar with MQTT protocol

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-1-introducing-mqtt
[MQTT basic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijwrS.png)